# Bypass authentication pop up in python (Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am having a problem that when I run my script it brakes giving me this error message:

> Alert Text: None Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog:
>   http://(CompanyServerName) is requesting your username and password.
>   WARNING: Your password will not be sent to the website you are
>   currently visiting!

Now the problem is that in 99% of cases I don't get a pop up window where I can enter my credentials.

I would like to either force or bypass an authentication window to pop up every time I run the script.

```
def init_driver():
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    caps['marionette'] = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    return driver

xpath = {
    'english': '//*[@id="cpcEnglish"]',

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    driver.get("http://SomeWebsite")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath['english']).click()
```

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath['english']).click()` is where my script breaks giving me the above mentioned message but not giving me an option to enter my credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around this is :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    driver = init_driver()
    try:
        driver.get("http://SomeWebsite")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id$=cpcEnglish]').click()
    except Exception:
        DoNothing = ""


    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id$=cpcEnglish]').click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

This will bypass the alert message and your script will continue